# How to pass json from java to javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, json

I make from my database a json string and i want to pass it to my javascript function, and print it into a html table. I use angular to make it easy to print the table, but i don't know how can i sent the data from java to javascript.
These is what i tried in java.

```
public void jsonRetr (String numeRepo) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + numeRepo;
    PreparedStatement prStm = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = prStm.executeQuery(sql);
    ArrayList<PersoaneJSON> persoane = new ArrayList<PersoaneJSON>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        String id = rs.getString("id");
        String login_name = rs.getString("login_name");
        String email = rs.getString("email");
        String public_gits = rs.getString("public_gits");
        String Html_profile = rs.getString("Html_profile");
        String Avatar_URL = rs.getString("Avatar_URL");

        PersoaneJSON persoana = new PersoaneJSON(id, login_name, email, public_gits, Html_profile, Avatar_URL);
        persoane.add(persoana);
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(persoane);
    }
```

These is what i tried in javascript.

```
    var employeeApp = angular.module("EmployeeApp",[]);
    employeeApp.controller("empCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.query = {}
    $scope.queryBy = '$'
    $scope.employees = [];
    $scope.orderProp="name";                
  });
```

Comment: So far you don't actually send anything, but using Gson for formatting is good enough.

Comment: So how can i sand the data, this is the problem for me, because i am a beginer and i don't know how to starte @M.Prokhorov

Answer (score 1):

I do some changes in your code (you can apply whatever you like)

```
public ArrayList<PersoaneJSON> jsonRetr (String numeRepo) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + numeRepo;
    PreparedStatement prStm = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = prStm.executeQuery(sql);
    ArrayList<PersoaneJSON> persoane = new ArrayList<PersoaneJSON>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        String id = rs.getString("id");
        String login_name = rs.getString("login_name");
        String email = rs.getString("email");
        String public_gits = rs.getString("public_gits");
        String Html_profile = rs.getString("Html_profile");
        String Avatar_URL = rs.getString("Avatar_URL");

        PersoaneJSON persoana = new PersoaneJSON(id, login_name, email, public_gits, Html_profile, Avatar_URL);
        persoane.add(persoana);
    }
   return persoane;
}
```

And here is Servlet doGet Method.

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


                response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");


                Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(jsonRetr("xyz"));

                out.write(json);
                out.close();

    }
```

Use jquery and read your json object as follows

```
$.getJSON( "Action/Servlet", function( data ) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

Comment: You can try http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm as well to parse your object to json.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Java Servlet with WebMethod, so call that method which can return a JSON object containing data.

Example
Java code:

ApplicationConfig.java

```
package example;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    resources.add(QueryResource.class);
    return resources;
  }
}
```

QueryResource.java

```
package example;


@Path("query")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class QueryResource {          

    @GET
    @Path("/employee")
    public String jsonRetr() throws Exception {
        ..
        return json;
    }
}
```

Now in js, inside your controller you can creater a function to connect to Servlet, passing $http Object to controller like $scope.

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8086/example/webresources/query/employee").success(function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            }).error(function () {
                console.error('error');
            });
```

In your web.xml you have to setup a configuration like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webresources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>        
   <servletclass>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servletclass>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
          <param-value>example.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        </servlet>
```

You need these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.26-b01</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.26-b01</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Hope this helps